# Sutras are in which Tripitaka

Tags: vipassana, sutras, nirvana, academic-buddhism

I have one query. All the Sutra's ( lotus Sutra, heart Sutra) belongs to which Tripitaka (first second or third)?

Answer (score 1):

The Tripitaka is one and it is divided in  three collections of texts (pitaka) and the first one contains the sutras (sutra pitaka).

The heart sutra and the lotus sutra are *not* in the Tripitaka though, they are part of the prajnaparamita sutras that is a different collection of sutras, studied in Mahāyāna Buddhism.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia's [Tripiṭaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripi%E1%B9%ADaka) article,

> Tripiṭaka has become a term used for many schools' collections, although their general divisions do not match a strict division into three piṭakas.

The "three baskets" to not correspond to the [Three Turnings of the Wheel of Dharma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Turnings_of_the_Wheel_of_Dharma) which is I think what the question is suggesting.

At least in the Wikipedia article, the different (versions of the) Tripiṭakas are referred to or named as "Pali", "Chinese", and "Tibetan".

The [Lotus Sutra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotus_Sutra) is not in the Pali Tripiṭaka -- apparently it was Indian originally, and translated into Chinese and Tibetan (and other languages).

And the [Heart Sutra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_Sutra) is apparently originally Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: the Mahayana sutras like Heart Sutra, Lotus Sutra are not part of the Tripitaka.

For the Theravada school, the main scripture is the [Pali Canon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripi%E1%B9%ADaka) or the Tipitaka, in the Pali language.

[Tipitaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripi%E1%B9%ADaka) or Tripitaka means the three baskets. The three are the Sutta Pitaka which is the basket on the teachings of the Buddha and his disciples, the Vinaya Pitaka which is the basket on the monastic rules, and the Abhidhamma Pitaka which is the basket of philosophical analysis.

Here's one view of it below. You can find it online at [AccessToInsight](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/index.html) or [SuttaCentral](https://suttacentral.net/).

Other Buddhist scripture for Mahayana Buddhism are either in [Sanskrit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanskrit_Buddhist_literature), [Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_Buddhist_canon) or [Tibetan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tibetan_Buddhist_canon). The Vajrayana school is part of Mahayana.

The Mahayana Agamas are equivalent to the Pali suttas.

However, the Mahayana sutras like Heart Sutra, Lotus Sutra are not part of the Tripitaka.

[image]